# how to create multiple objects and enumerate them in c#

Tags: c#

my problem is as follows:

Im building a console application which asks the user for the numbers of objects it should create and 4 variables that have to be assigned for every object.
The new objects name should contain a counting number starting from 1.

How would you solve this?
Im thinking about a class but im unsure about how to create the objects in runtime from userinput. Is a loop the best way to go?

What kind of class, struct, list, array .... would you recommend. The variables in the object are always the same type but i need to name them properly so I can effectivly write methods to perform operations on them in a later phase of the program.

Im just learning the language and I would be very thankful for a advice on how to approach my problem.

Comment: This smells like a homework problem

Comment: @Doug R: Possibly, but he certainly hasn't copy/pasted the problem statement -- this seems more like his attempt at a solution. Thing is, I don't understand what he's trying to do or why. @Daniel: Do you want to dynamically instantiate a class of a particular type using the user's input for the type name, or are you wanting the user to be able to create a new type based on the user's input? If you're creating a new type... what are you doing with it afterward? Frankly, this seems like it's an overly complex solution to what is likely a simple problem.

Comment: Homework questions are ok as long as they are not of the "here's a problem, give me an answer" variety.

Comment: @Ed: Exactly. This isn't a bad question because it might be homework related, it's a bad question because it's not clear enough. This may be because of the asker's unfamiliarity with programming in general and/or C# in particular.

Comment: no it's not homework... would it matter?
Anyhow I'm sorry for my confuse description of the topic.
 
I'll try to explain my problem a little more abstract:

I have some real live objects and i need to perform "calculations" on their attributes. These attributes are always the same only the values are changing. Now what i wanna do is create a number of consecutively numbered objects and assign values to the attributes I previously decleared.
The number of objects and the values for each object shall be obtained from Console user input. This process is going to be repeated very very often.

Comment: @[daniel richter]: edit the question with the clarification instead of putting it in a comment; not everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int ObjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string SomeVariable { get; set; }
    public string AnotherVariable { get; set; }
}

// You should use keyboard input value for this 
int objectsToCreate = 10;

// Create an array to hold all your objects
MyClass[] myObjects = new MyClass[objectsToCreate];

for (int i = 0; i < objectsToCreate; i++)
{
    // Instantiate a new object, set it's number and
    // some other properties
    myObjects[i] = new MyClass()
    {
        ObjectNumber = i + 1,
        SomeVariable = "SomeValue",
        AnotherVariable = "AnotherValue"
    };
}
```

This doesn't quite do what you described. Add in keyboard input and stuff :) Most of this code needs to be in some kind of `Main` method to actually run, etc.

In this case, I've chosen a `class` to hold your 4 variables. I have only implemented 3 though, and I've implemented them as *properties*, rather than fields. I'm not sure this is necessary for your assignment, but it is generally a good habit to not have publically accessible fields, and I don't want to be the one to teach you bad habits. See [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

You mentioned a `struct`, which would be an option as well, depending on what you want to store in it. Generally though, a class would be a safer bet.

A loop would indeed be the way to go to initialize your objects. In this case, a `for` loop is most practical. It starts counting at `0`, because we're putting the objects in an array, and array indexes in C# always start at `0`. This means you have to use `i + 1` to assign to the object number, or the objects would be numbered 0 - 9, just like their indexes in the array.

I'm initializing the objects using [object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx), which is new in C# 3.0.
The old fashioned way would be to assign them one by one:

```
myObjects[i] = new MyClass();
myObjects[i].ObjectNumber = i + 1;
myObjects[i].SomeVariable = "SomeValue";
```

Alternatively, you could define a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) for `MyClass` that takes 3 parameters.

One last thing: some people here posted answers which use a *generic List* (`List<MyClass>`) instead of an array. This will work fine, but in my example I chose to use the most basic form you could use. A List does not have a fixed size, unlike an array (notice how I initialized the array). Lists are great if you want to add more items later, or if you have no idea beforehand how many items you will need to store. However, in this case, we have the keyboard input, so we know exactly how many items we'll have. Thus: array. It will implicitly tell whoever is reading your code, that you do not intend to add more items later.

I hope this answered some questions, and raised some new ones. See just how deep the rabbit hole goes :P

Answer (score 0):

Use a list or an array. List example:

```
int numberOfObjects = 3;
List<YourType> listOfObjects = new List<YourType>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfObjects ; i++ ) 
{
    // Get input and create object ....
    // Then add to your list
    listOfObjects.Add(element);
}
```

Here, listOfObjects is a Generic list that can contain a variable number of objects of the type YourType. The list will automatically resize so it can hold the number of objects you add to it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually sound more like a `Dictionary<int,foo>` (for a custom class foo) with the "name" requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is an actual requirement, or just because he needs to get more confortable with the concept of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking you could probably do something like this:

```
class Foo 
{
   private static int count;
   public string name;
   public Foo(...){
     name = ++count + "";
   }
}
```

Comment: I've thought about that, but I thought it better to discourage such a pattern at this point. If you wanted to make absolutely sure no object has the same number / name, you could enforce it like this. Then again, you should probably add a `volatile` to your static variable in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you're trying to do here, but this is a stab in the dark. The problem I'm having is dealing with the whole "the new objects name should contain a counting number starting from 1" thing. Anyway, here's my attempt:

```
public class UserInstantiatedClass
{
   public int UserSetField1;
   public int UserSetField2;
   public int UserSetField3;
   public int UserSetField4;
   public string UserSpecifiedClassName;
}

public static class MyProgram
{
   public static void Main(string [] args) 
   {
      // gather user input, place into variables named 
      // numInstances, className, field1, field2, field3, field4
      List<UserInstantiatedClass> instances = new List< UserInstantiatedClass>();
      UserInstantiatedClass current = null;
      for(int i=1; i<=numInstances; i++)
      {
         current = new UserInstantiatedClass();
         current.UserSpecifiedClassName = className + i.ToString(); // adds the number 1, 2, 3, etc. to the class name specified
         current.UserSetField1 = field1;
         current.UserSetField2 = field2;
         current.UserSetField3 = field3;
         current.UserSetField4 = field4;
         instances.Add(current);
      }
      // after this loop, the instances list contains the number of instances of the class UserInstantiatedClass specified by the numInstances variable.  
   }
}
```